# Connection Docker (IBM Integration Bus) to DataCache

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, websphere-extreme-scale

I can't connect to the DataCache Service in Bluemix from a docker container even though the service is bound to it.

What I have done:

1. I clone the docker image from the official repository (https://github.com/ot4i/iib-docker)
2. I created the the DataCache Service in Bluemix
3. Customized the docker file to to read the VCAPS for the data cache and then ran the command to configure IIB to use an external extreme scale (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bn23788_.htm?cp=SSMKHH_10.0.0%2F9-7-3-2-1&lang=en) and then automatically restarted iib in the docker container.

But I can't reach the DataCache neither from IIB nor with a ping / telnet from the DataService. Is there a way to make this happen?

Thanks and Best Regards
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to connect from an IBM container running on Bluemix to a Bluemix service instance you have to be sure that:
- the service instance has been created in the same space of the container which you would like to connect to
- you have created a bridge app in the same space like described by the Bluemix documentation
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_integrations.html